# Telegram Bot Auto Hold To Copy

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I am using java programming to develop a telgram bot. Generally `text` make monospace which if we click on text its auto get copy to clipboard.
How can I make this on telegram bot? I tried to use ` this back quote for this but did not worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just asked a feature of telegram bot how can I click a text on that was send from telegram bot it will auto copy to clipboard. Here nothing to add code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `code` html tag to send a message with text that can be copied by clicking on it (works on Android, iOS and even Telegram Desktop).

```java
String messageText = "Click on the text to copy it to clipboard: <code>Hello world!</code>";
```

Please note that for this to work you have to specify `parse_mode="HTML"` when sending the message, as specified in the [Formatting options](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) section of the Telegram Bot API.

Alternatively, putting the text into backticks with `parse_mode="markdown"` works as well.