# create button 'copy' telegram api

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api, node-telegram-bot-api

I am creating a simple telegram bot. I send a message from the server:
[https://api.telegram.org/bot{API_KEY}/sendMessage?chat_id={CHAT_ID}&text={TEXT_MESSAGE}](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7BAPI_KEY%7D/sendMessage?chat_id=%7BCHAT_ID%7D&text=%7BTEXT_MESSAGE%7D)

I would like to attach a button to it, when clicked, a certain link would be copied to the clipboard.
I've searched all over the Internet, and I just can't figure out how to create buttons.
Please, help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you created a button in the chat with your bot, it's impossible to write a functionality that would copy given text to clipboard by clicking the button (see [Is it possible in Telegram to copy to clipboard by button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678191/is-it-possible-in-telegram-to-copy-to-clipboard-by-button)).

One option how to copy a text to clipboard by clicking on it would be to use `code` HTML tag, as shown here: [Telegram Bot Auto Hold To Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004523/telegram-bot-auto-hold-to-copy).